# How to rewrite only in these cases?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a way to redirect ALL and ONLY urls that starts with folders: **"home/"** and **"car/"**, from example.com to jp.example.com.

So for example:

```
example.com/home/test.html ---> jp.example.com/home/test.html
example.com/car/test.html ---> jp.example.com/car/test.html
jp.example.com/home/second-test.html ---> jp.example.com/home/second-test.html
jp.example.com/third-test.html ---> example.com/third-test.html
```

I am using this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^jp.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://jp.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

But it doesn't work because it rewrite all urls from example.com to jp.example.com

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check to see if the URI requested either begins with `/home` or `/car`, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^jp.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/home|/car)(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://jp.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

# conditions 1 & 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(home|care)/ http://jp.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]

# conditions 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jp\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(home)/second_(test\.html)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]

# conditions 4
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jp\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(third-test\.html)$ http://%1/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```